# Clarification on the gradient of $f(x) := \frac{1}{2}\left\| X (a+b) \right\|_2^2 + \mu \operatorname{Re}\left\{a^H X b\right\}$

Tags: matrix-calculus

I would like to compute the gradient of the following function
\begin{align}
f(x) := \frac{1}{2}\left\| X (a+b) \right\|_2^2 + \mu \operatorname{Re}\left\{a^H X b\right\}
\end{align}
where $X:= \operatorname{Diag}(x)$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, and $a,b \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times 1}$.

The gradient that I compute is the following:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = x \odot (a+b) \odot (a+b) + \mu\operatorname{Re}\left\{ a^* \odot b\right\} \ .
\end{align}

**Question**: Is my above gradient not correct?

Comment: Assuming $f$ is real, the first term is missing a complex conjugate: $$x\odot(a+b)^*\odot(a+b) + \mu\,{\cal Re}(a^*\odot b)$$

Comment: Thank you so much, greg, for the correction.